# Prevent Area plot Y-axis from starting with ZERO

Tags: javascript, highcharts

What is the configuration for Y-axis to not start with ZERO but rather start with value close to lowest Y-axis data point  in HighCharts/HighStock?

Here is the demo of chart which has a very great Y-axis data values while the minimal Y-axis plot point is ZERO: http://jsfiddle.net/ubnjjups/

and sample configuration used in the demo:

```
{
  series: [{
    type: 'area',
    data: [
      [1375660800000, 106861],
      [1375747200000, 107397],
      [1375833600000, 108674],
      [1375920000000, 108792],
      [1376006400000, 110504],
      [1376265600000, 110658],
      [1376352000000, 110792]
    ]
  }],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using 'area' type which by definition needs to show you area from 0 to the point.  If you switch to say 'spline', it automatically does what you want.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
  series: [{
    type: 'spline',
    data: [[1375660800000, 106861],[1375747200000, 107397],[1375833600000, 108674],[1375920000000, 108792],[1376006400000, 110504],[1376265600000, 110658],[1376352000000, 110792],[1376438400000, 111095],[1376524800000, 112334],[1376611200000, 112775],[1376870400000, 113051],[1376956800000, 113426],[1377043200000, 113516]]
  }],
});
```

});

UPDATE:

If you want to continue to use Area chart (so you have filled area under), I recommend you use min on your yAxis. I have changed your code here

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
      series: [{
        type: 'area',
        data: [[1375660800000, 106861],[1375747200000, 107397],[1375833600000, 108674],[1375920000000, 108792],[1376006400000, 110504],[1376265600000, 110658],[1376352000000, 110792],[1376438400000, 111095],[1376524800000, 112334],[1376611200000, 112775],[1376870400000, 113051],[1376956800000, 113426],[1377043200000, 113516]]
      }],
        yAxis:{
         min: 105000
        }
    });
});
```

The value of min can be calculated ahead of time when you get your data back from the server and calculate your minimum value point.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. However, your example doesn't have a filled area under the line. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: I wish Highcharts had a configuration option that would do that automatically. I will set yAxis.min as you suggest for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Vadim's answer, as of today I suggest calculating lowest Y-axis value inside the `yAxis.min` configuration itself to keep code consistent and portable. The only requirement is to extract the data into a variable outside the chart initialization.

With data in format `<Timestamp>, <Y-axis value>` following would work:

```
var data = [
  [1375660800000, 106861],
  [1375747200000, 107397],
  [1375833600000, 108674]
];

$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

  series: [{
    type: 'area',
    data: data
  }],

  yAxis: {
    min: (function() {
      var min = data[0][1];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var value = data[i][1];
        if (value < min) {
          min = value;  
        }
      }
      return min;
    })()
  }

});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/squuwqmg/